# Parametric surfaces with dependent parameters

Tags: pstricks, 3d, pst-solides3d, pspicture

I'm trying to create an image that shows (for example) the portion of a standard cylinder (\cos(v),\sin(v),u) that lies between the planes z=0 and z+y=5.  Generating the cylinder itself is not an issue, but I would need to set the bounds for u from 0 to 5-\sin(v), which pstricks seems to hate; it gives me an Invalid argument error.  Is there some simple way around this that I'm missing?

Edit:  By request, what I'm trying right now thanks to Herbert.  At this point I get no errors, but it gets hung up indefinitely in the compile:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-10,-10)(10,15) 
\psset{
unit=1.0,
Decran=50,
viewpoint=15 55 35 rtp2xyz,
lightsrc=20 60 20 rtp2xyz,
ngrid=50 50,  
grid,  
resolution=720
}

\defFunction[algebraic]{cylinder}(u,v){cos(v)}{sin(v)}{u}

\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
base=0 2 pi pi neg,  
function=cylinder,
incolor=red!30,
fillcolor=red!30,
opacity=0.4,
plansepare={[0 0 1 -1]},
name=partiescylindre,
]

\axesIIID(0,0,0)(2,2,3)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I remember a graphic very similar, that your case, in this page; but using tikz or pgfplots. But I don't remember the link nor tags. :(

Comment: give an example what you already tried.

Comment: @Herbert: I'm on a mobile right now, but as I said the cylinder draws just fine with u from 0 to 5 and v from pi to pi neg.  But if I change the 5 to anything involving a v, I get an Invalid argument error.

Comment: your example dosn't hang, but it needs in fact of `ngrid=50 50,` a lot of time for the calculations. However, in the end there is a postscript error. I must have a look at it

Comment: @Herbert: You're right, I changed it to `ngrid=5 30` and it loads much faster.  I must have just been impatient with my slow machine.  I see the error now too; it goes away if I comment out the `plansepare` line.  I've seen this error before when fooling around and using a plane that doesn't intersect the surface at all, but that shouldn't be the case this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-5)(6,8)
    \psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=100 30 40 rtp2xyz,Decran=100}
    \psSolid[object=grille,base=-4 4 -4 4,ngrid=8](0,0,-1)
    \defFunction[algebraic]{G9}(t){1*cos(t)}{1*sin(t)}{1*sin(5*t)}
    \psSolid[object=cylindre,range=0 6.28,h=5,function=G9,axe=0 0 1,
             incolor=green!50,fillcolor=yellow!50,linewidth=0.01,ngrid=10 72](0,-3,0)
    \psSolid[object=cylindre,r=1,h=5,incolor=green!50,fillcolor=yellow!50,
             ngrid=5 36](0,3,0)
    \psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,opacity=0.5,args={[0 1 1 -5] 180},
             planmarks,plangrid,base=-2 2 -2 2,showBase]
    \psSolid[object=cylindre,range=0 6.28,h=5,function=G9,axe=0 0 1,
             incolor=green!50,fillcolor=yellow!50,plansepare={[0 1 1 -5]},
             name=partiescylindre,
             linewidth=0.01,ngrid=10 72]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: YES, the `plansepare` command is exactly what I was looking for.  I notice that you use a pre-defined cylinder function.  do you know if it will work for general parametric surfaces?  I included some code in an edit above; without the `plansepare` and `name` parameters it works just fine, but with them it seems to get hung up indefinitely.  I get no errors, it just doesn't finish compiling.